# Function call after recursive function returns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I am having a recursive function in some service class to remove some json elements and once they are removed I have to call the callbacks registered for the updates.

My Code -

```
    var trimTree = function(){
    removeScripts(tree.children).then(function(){
      angular.forEach(callbacks, function(callback){
        //console.log(callback);
        console.log("Calling callbacks");
        callback();
      });
    });
  }
  function removeScripts(nodes){
    for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
      if(nodes[i].type == 'script'){
        return nodes.splice(i, 1);
      }else{
        return removeScripts(nodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

But its giving me error as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Thanks

Comment: removeScripts doesn't return a promise, so you can't use .then. you might need to use $q to create a promise https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: @NitsanBaleli, Promise is not needed in `sync` operations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assuming `removeScripts()` returns a Promise, it does not. `removeScripts()` is sync, so just add statements after it normally.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
function removeScripts(nodes){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
    if(nodes[i].type == 'script'){
      deferred.resolve(nodes.splice(i, 1));
    }else{
      deferred.reject(removeScripts(nodes[i]));
    }
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

You need to use [Deferred API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).